# Making pig embedded with python script and pig cassandra integration to work with oozie

Tags: python, hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig, oozie

I am new to oozie and I have few problems. 
1) I am trying to embed a pig action in oozie which has a python script import. I've placed the jython.jar file in the lib path and have an import in the pig script which will take the python UDFs. I don't seems to get this working. The .py file is not getting picked up. How to go about this?
2) I have a pig cassandra integration where in I use the cql to get the data from cassandra using pig and do some basic transformation. In the CLI i am able to get this working. But on the oozie front I am not. I don't seem to find the solution(configuration and others) to do this in oozie. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. Solutions..

1) Put the python file in the oozie worklow path and then reference if from here.

2) Added cassandra jar files in the lib folder in the oozie's HDFS path.